# Do Killing vectors form a Lie-algebra?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, vector-fields, lie-algebra

In Arnold's book on "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" it is said that vector fields  on manifolds form a Lie-algebra (see chapter 8 on sympletic geometry/manifolds). I consider that Killing vectors are such vector fields, so they should form a Lie-algebra. However, for instance the Kerr-metric (of a rotating black hole) has 2 Killing vectors, putting them in a commutator I could so obtain a third one. But I wonder if that is really the case. Because in the literature resources (for instance Wald, GR 1983 nor Wikipedia) this property is not mentioned. So form Killing vectors a Lie algebra or not (or do they only under particular circumstances)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/119688/

Comment: Of course this is mentioned [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field#Properties): *"The Killing fields on a manifold M thus form a Lie subalgebra of vector fields on M."*

Comment: Ok I must have overlooked that. So in Kerr-metric I can make out of 2 3 Killing-vectors?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The Lie bracket of two vector fields is not necessarily a linearly independent vector field (in particular it can simply be zero). Have you tried computing the Lie bracket of the two particular Killing vectors you're talking about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let us start from the property of the Lie derivative $$[L_X,L_Y] :=L_XL_Y -L_YL_X = L_{\{X,Y\}}.\tag{1}$$

The Killing condition for the vector field $X$ is $L_Xg=0$ where $g$ is the metric. That is equivalent to the more popular one $\nabla_aX_b + \nabla_b X_a=0$.

It is now immediate to prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are Killing then $\{X,Y\}$ is Killing  just by using (1) and the definition above of Killing field:

$$L_{\{X,Y\}}g =L_X(L_Yg) -L_Y(L_Xg)= 0+0 =0.$$

The conclusion is that the Killing fields form a Lie algebra with respect to the Lie parenthesis of vector fields. It is possible to prove that the dimension of it is always finite.

In particular, the Lie commutator of the two Killing fields of the Kerr metric must be a Killing vector as well.

Reference: my lecture [notes](https://moretti.maths.unitn.it/manifolds.pdf) (with still many typos)